# Can i upload a sub-domain in different cpanel?

Tags: subdomain, cpanel

I have a website. It's name suppose `www.example.com`. Now i create a `sub-domain` in my `c-panel`  name `www.test.example.com`Now i want to upload this `sub-domain` in another `c-panel` and I want to upload file that another `c-panel` my question is is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is too confusing however you can create a seperate account ( Primary account ) for the subdomain however since subdomains are associated with primary domain so you can create it in other domain's cpanel account.

So test.abc.com can not be created as subdomain for xyz.com